# Inject a function as a content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am injecting a content script on button press using [chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)

When injecting programaticaly I can pass in as either

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code:  "alert('hello world');"});
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file:  example.js});
```

I can pass in a string or a file to execute.  Is there a way to inject a function.

something like

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: function1});

function function1() { alert("hi");}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't inject into a content script a function defined in a background page. However, you can get the function source code and make it immediately invoked.

```
function hello() { alert("hi"); }

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "(" + hello.toString() + ")()" });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about embedding the function definition within the code snippet itself?

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
     code: "function function1() { alert('hi'))};
            function1();"
 });
```

Comment: The idea is to define multiple functions in the background page and only inject the one which is needed.  This would be the same as injecting a file with all the functions declared.